# Is there a cachebust variable in mkdocs templates?

Tags: caching, jinja2, mkdocs

Is there anything like `{{ time() }}` or even more ideally `{{ sha1sum('main.js') }}` which I could use as a cachebust parameter in my theme templates?

Yes I'm aware of server side caching headers, but I don't have control of those.

Answer (score 0):

The best I found so far is this `{{ build_date_utc.strftime('%S%f') }}` based on documentation I found here: http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/custom-themes/#template-variables

So now I can do this: 
`<script src="/static/js/main.js?cb={{ build_date_utc.strftime('%S%f') }}">`

Which invalidates the cached file much more than it should, but at least it solves the problem.